# Converting a 24-Hour clock with Images to 12-Hour clock with AM and PM with Day and Date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typography, real-time-clock

I have a HTML/Java clock program which used images and is currently in 24-Hour format, what I'm hoping to get done is to have it in a 12-Hour format and also display AM/PM with the Day and Date. Is that something possible?
I'm trying to create a indic clock with different scripts here.

Here's the current code.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Indic Clock</title>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #FAF7EC">

    <center> Devanagiri </center>

    <div id="Clock">
        <img id="hour1" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img id="hour2" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img src="dots.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img id="minute1" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img id="minute2" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img src="dots.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img id="second1" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
        <img id="second2" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var images = new Array('0.png', '1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png', '8.png', '9.png',);

    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        var date = new Date();

        var hour = String(date.getHours());
        var minutes = String(date.getMinutes());
        var seconds = String(date.getSeconds());

        if(hour < 10)
        {
            $('#hour1').attr('src', images[0]);
            $('#hour2').attr('src', images[hour.charAt(0)]);

        }
        else
        {

            $('#hour1').attr('src', images[hour.charAt(0)]);
            $('#hour2').attr('src', images[hour.charAt(1)]);

        }

        if(minutes < 10)
        {
            $('#minute1').attr('src', images[0]);
            $('#minute2').attr('src', images[minutes.charAt(0)]);

        }
        else
        {

            $('#minute1').attr('src', images[minutes.charAt(0)]);
            $('#minute2').attr('src', images[minutes.charAt(1)]);

        }

        if(seconds < 10)
        {
            $('#second1').attr('src', images[0]);
            $('#second2').attr('src', images[seconds.charAt(0)]);

        }
        else
        {

            $('#second1').attr('src', images[seconds.charAt(0)]);
            $('#second2').attr('src', images[seconds.charAt(1)]);

        }

    }, 1000)


</script>

</body>
```

I have tried to bring in Date and was able to get it to work, but I'm still confused with 12-Hour format with AM/PM and bring in the Day (for ex. MON for Monday, TUE for Tuesday and so on)

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: @Kshitij Gotiwale "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to 12-hour format like below

do it like below:

```
var timeformat = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour12: true });
var timeformatArr = timeformat.split(' ');
var ampm = timeformatArr[1];
var timeArr = timeformatArr[0].split(':');
```

Working snippet:

```js
var images = new Array('https://pngimg.com/uploads/number0/number0_PNG19185.png', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200309/ourmid/pngtree-gold-number-1-png-image_2158836.jpg', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200309/ourmid/pngtree-gold-number-2-png-image_2158838.jpg', 'https://freepngimg.com/download/numbers/5-2-3-number-png.png', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200401/original/pngtree-gold-number-4-png-image_5330869.jpg', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200401/original/pngtree-gold-number-5-png-image_5330870.jpg', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20210204/ourmid/pngtree-gold-3d-number-six-numeric-symbol-png-image_2884744.jpg', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200401/original/pngtree-gold-number-7-png-image_5330848.jpg', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200309/ourmid/pngtree-gold-number-8-png-image_2158851.jpg', 'https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20200309/ourmid/pngtree-gold-number-9-png-image_2158853.jpg', 'https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/010/885/807/non_2x/3d-number-10-mental-yellow-free-png.png', 'https://img.lovepik.com/free-png/20210919/lovepik-countdown-number-11-png-image_400762906_wh1200.png', 'https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/010/885/817/non_2x/3d-number-12-mental-yellow-free-png.png');

var ampmImages = ['https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/874/385/png-transparent-brand-logo-font-who-am-i-angle-text-triangle-thumbnail.png','https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1584/1584790.png'];

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timeformat = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour12: true });
  var timeformatArr = timeformat.split(' ');
  var ampm = timeformatArr[1];
  var timeArr = timeformatArr[0].split(':');
  
  var hour = timeArr[0] % 12;
  hour = hour ? hour : 12;
  hour =  hour < 10 ? '0'+hour : hour;
  hour = String(hour);
  
  var minutes = timeArr[1] < 10 ? '0'+timeArr[1] : timeArr[1];  
  var seconds = timeArr[2] < 10 ? '0'+timeArr[2] : timeArr[2];


  $('#hour1').attr('src', images[hour.charAt(0)]);
  $('#hour2').attr('src', images[hour.charAt(1)]);

  $('#minute1').attr('src', images[minutes.charAt(0)]);
  $('#minute2').attr('src', images[minutes.charAt(1)]);

  $('#second1').attr('src', images[seconds.charAt(0)]);
  $('#second2').attr('src', images[seconds.charAt(1)]);
  $('#ampm').attr('src', (ampm == 'AM') ? ampmImages[0]:ampmImages[1]);

}, 1000);
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Indic Clock</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #FAF7EC">

  <center> Devanagiri </center>

  <div id="Clock">
    <img id="hour1" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img id="hour2" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/dot/dot_PNG22.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img id="minute1" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img id="minute2" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/dot/dot_PNG22.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img id="second1" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img id="second2" src="0.png" width="150" height="275" />
    <img id="ampm" src="" width="150" height="275" />
  </div>
</body>
```